# New Ubuntu setup for a small office

Tags: networking, server, client

New to Ubuntu and networking in general.

I have been tasked at my office to setup a 'system' for 5 desktops (hardwired), 4 laptops (wireless), 1 wireless color printer, 1 wired laser MFP, 1 wired laser printer.

Network equipment we already have:
Linksys Etherfast 4116 switch, Linksys/Cisco wireless router, DSL connection

Computer equipment:
5 BASIC desktops containing 4 GB RAM, various size hard drives (1 in each one), simple video card, sound card, monitor, keyboard, mouse

I have added a D-Link ShareCenter for files connected to the 4116.

I will be adding a 'server' to which I would like to install Ubuntu, OpenOffice, Acrobat pro, etc., in addition I would like to turn the current desktops into clients.

Where do I start and what should I be putting in place?

Comment: Will you be using Ubuntu as a client (on desktops) or server? If as a server, why OpenOffice, Acrobat Pro, etc on a server?

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to really need a "server" if the shared files are going to be kept on the D-Link NAS.  You would be installing the applications (such as LibreOffice, Acrobat, etc) on each of the "clients", not on a central server.

In theory you could set up a headless PXE boot environment where the clients acted as thin clients - google LTSP, Linux Terminal Server Project for details - but this is almost certainly going to be be both overkill and considerably more complex to get running than your stated experience level sounds compatible with.  (Feel free to prove me wrong, get started, and come back later with specific questions about an LTSP project you've made some headway on! :)